# Why when I reverse the comparison sign in my bubble sort algorithm does the resulting sorting list not reverse?

Tags: java, sorting, reverse, bubble-sort

Java Code:

```
    public static NHLList bubbleSort(NHLList players) {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < players.size()-1; j++) {
                if (players.get(j).getPoints() < players.get(j+1).getPoints()) {
                    PlayerRecord tempPlayer = players.get(j);
                    players.set(players.get(j+1), j);
                    players.set(tempPlayer, j+1);
                }
            }
        }
        return players;
    }
```

If I change `j < ...` to `j > ...` the resulting list is not the previous list inverted, though I would assume it should be. All it's doing is reading numbers.

Comment: Are you changing this line: `players.get(j).getPoints() < players.get(j+1).getPoints()`, right?

Comment: And NOT in this line `for (int j = 0; j < players.size()-1; j++) {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*rolls sleeves up*

You're inverting the sign on the wrong line.

Comment: Side note: why not just make PlayerRecord `comparable`?

Comment: Excuse my naivety, but what exactly does that mean?

Comment: Java provides a whole bunch of stuff you can use to help with **sorting**. If you want to sort a collection of `PlayerRecord` objects, you can mark them as `comparable` by adding `implements Comparable` to the class declaration. You must then provide an ` int compareTo(PlayerRecord p)` method, which returns -1, 0 or 1. You can then just do things like `myCollection.sort()` without having to re-invent the wheel. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html for the docs.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, please specify which line you are editing. If you are editing the right line then you may be unhappy to hear that this is **not actually implementing** `BubbleSort`.

You are actually performing a complete scan of the list `n` times which may, under some circumstances, result in a sorted list but is not actually what `BubbleSort` is all about. I would suggest you study your code and try to work out for yourself why your loop-counter `i` is never being referred to in the code (apart from in the loop control).